# Counter not incrementing with IF statement inside FOR loop in Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, scripting, batch-file

I have a simple FOR loop inside of a batch file I'm creating that isn't quite working the way I'm expecting.  The FOR loop iterates through lines of a text file, and on each iteration, I use an IF statement to make a quick comparison on the current line, and do some work if it evaluates to true.  Here is the code:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /a sitecounts=1
set /a input=34
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^/" %%G IN (file.txt) DO (
IF %sitecounts% == %input% (set /a selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H)
set /a sitecounts=!sitecounts!+1
echo !sitecounts!
)
```

I'm running into a weird issue where, the **sitecounts** variable (my counter) actually increments properly with each loop (I prove this by echoing out the count with the last statement) -- BUT upon the next iteration **%sitecounts%** still shows that it has the value of '1', which was the initial value.

If I change the code to:

```
IF !sitecounts! == ...
```

...then the IF statement appears to treat that value as pure TEXT!  I've set ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION to handle variables within loops, but not sure what to do next.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It might be worth learning PowerShell.  Windows BAT files are quite limited.

Comment: While powershell may be worth learning, Windows batch scripts are easily up to this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This time I actually tested it....

Change the line

```
IF %sitecounts% == %input% (set /a selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H)
```

into

```
IF !sitecounts! == %input% (set selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H)
```

- `%sitecounts%` needs to be `!sitecounts!` in order to be evaluated
- `set /a selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H` doesn't work because it is not a numerical expression:

  > The /A switch specifies that the string to the right of the equal sign
  >   is a numerical expression that is evaluated.

  Just omit the switch (`/p`  is not going to work neither, that's for a prompt)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is in this line

```
IF %sitecounts% == %input% (set /a selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H)
```

you are setting a **string** not a **numeric expression** (set /a), then change to

```
IF !sitecounts! == %input% (set   selectedsitepath=%logfilepath%W3SVC%%H)
   ^          ^                 ^
```

Comment: Yes, the switch was the culprit, but replacing it by `/p` is not the solution: _The /P switch allows you to set the value of a variable to a line of input
entered by the user._ In order to set a variable to a string value, no switch is needed.

Comment: @marapet right, just seen that /a /p in set help and thought that /p was for string. Answer updated